# After Python import, call to a definition is generating the NameError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm new to python and I was trying to do the following:

I have a folder called `app` and this folder has two files: main.py and **init**.py

The

```
main.py

def generate_report(x1, x2):
    print "Generating report..."
    print x1
    print x2 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Running: main.py..."

    generate_reports(1, 2)

    print "Done!"

else:
    print "Imported: main.py..."
```

The

```
__init__.py

import main
```

Now in my console if I do:

```
import app
```

I get:

```
Imported: main.py...
```

Then if I try to do:

```
generate_report(1, 2)
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'generate_report' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to do `main.generate_report`.

Comment: Tried that, now I get, NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different approaches to module namespaces in Python. In one, you do `import blah` and then access blah's elements with `blah.spam`. In another, you say `from blah import spam` (or `*`) and then access blah's elements directly by name.

The problem is, you have to make that decision on every level: if you have a package, you have two such decisions to make: how your script imports package (`app` in your case), and how your app's `__init__.py` imports `main` (btw a horrible name for a module;P).

So, one solution is to write

```
from app import main
```

in your `__init__.py`, and

```
from app import generate_report
```

in your script, and another is to write

```
app.main.generate_report
```

in your script. Of course, there are two other ways, where some import is direct, and some is `from`ed.